# Wanted to test the 0x protocol contracts on a testnet but fail to see how to get them deployed

Tags: 0x

I start here https://github.com/0xProject/protocol and look my way around. From my understanding, if I'm on the right track, I can start with ganache and get test cases and so forth going. Then getting them deployed would we use the ganache CLI to point to another network using migrations? If that's correct by poking around, I had no idea that was possible.

Overall goal here is to see how small changes would affect a live deployment on a testnet with an already supported network. I see other forks of the repo deploying contracts so problem on other testnets like avalanche.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I guess its can you use gananche-cli and point to a RPC like a mainnet/testnet rpc and have contracts deployed there rather than something local

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way these days is to fork off of mainnet (e.g Ethereum/Avalanche) and make use of that.

The protocol has aspects which depend on third party contracts (e.g the aggregation) so it's much easier to start from a forked RPC.